# Android Studio - Can't select "make module"

Tags: android, android-studio

[Screenshot of my Android Studio screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRDxS.png)

I get the error "module not specified" but I can't solve this problem because the "Make module" selection is not selectable for me. I don't understand why. Do someone know why ? And how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to make the Project because it contains some gradle errors which you can see in your configuration dialog.
So if you want to enable the Make project button, then find & solve the errors you have & it will be enabled automatically :)